# How do I install VirtualBox 5.2 + GUI on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed *VirtualBox* from the official Ubuntu repository:

- `virtualbox`
- `virtualbox-qt`
- `virtualbox-ext-pack`

After adding the official *Oracle VirtualBox* repository:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

And its key:

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc
```

I can now install `virtualbox-5.2`. **But it removes `virtualbox-qt` and `virtualbox-ext-pack`.**

How can I install VirtualBox 5.2 and have the GUI and the extension pack?

Comment: have you looked to see if Vbox is available to you .. click start and in the search type vitrualbox .. see if there is a start for it .. if so launch it it will ask you to download the ext pack

Comment: if that doesn't work go to the download page on the vbox website and download the one for Ubuntu 16.04 ("Xenial")  i386 |  AMD64) choose the one for your system 32 bit or 64 bit .. and just double click the deb file .. it should allow you to install it that way and again it will give you an option of downloading and installing the ext pack when you launch the program

Comment: I have exactly same question as I tried to install Virtualbox-5.2, it turns out that you don't need virtualbox-qt anymore, and I end up install virtualbox-ext-pack through Virtualbox itself(Virtualbox media amager), not through Ubuntu's package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All binaries, and the guest additions will be included on [installing from the Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack). Previous versions of virtualbox may conflict and will have to be removed manually, or will automatically be removed during installation. Existing virtual machines will be kept.

There is no point to download and install a DEB package in addition.

An extension pack matchin the installed version of virtualbox will have to be [manually downloaded](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and then [installed from the virtualbox media manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Comment: "There is no point to download and install a DEB package in addition" - i have cleaner source.list/keyring; to me makes sense to actually have the outside distribution/repository package

Comment: @user688056 the emphasis is on **in addition** here ;)

Comment: i jumped at repository vs .deb distribution.. interpreter/interpretation :)

Answer (score 3):

you cant have 2 versions of virtualbox at the same time;
you can install virtualbox from .deb package downloaded from

> [Linux_Downloads – Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)
>
> and extensions from
>
> [Downloads – Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) - look for  VirtualBox Extension Pack  **All supported platforms** link

first purge old version

> apt-get purge virtualbox

then download from links above required files and install

```
dpkg -i virtualbox.. #[downloaded file name] 
apt-get install -f  #[for fixing dependencies]
vboxmanage extpack install Oracle.. #[extension pack]
```

after this you should have virtualbox+GUI+ext pack

Comment: It's a bad idea to directly link to the vbox-extpack here which will be outdated in a few months an generates maintenance burden on your end or the risk of users following your answer to use old software. You can btw. do some nice scripting with curl LATEST-STABLE.TXT and wget. It's a good exercise but don't hurt the vbox donwload server with too many try and error attempts. :)

Comment: changed as suggestion link; overengineered.. 2 much script work for 2 easily spotted links..  :)

Answer (score 2):

Have exactly same issue, turns out in virtualbox-5.2 or even earlier version, you don't need virtualbox-qt anymore for a GUI.

I still need download the Ext pack, from Virtualbox website, but it's now a plug-in, and are not OS depended anymore, so it is not necessary to be managed by Ubuntu's package manager.