# Is it possible to install LineageOS on a device using Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, android, tablet, smartphone

**LineageOS**, an [Android Distribution](https://lineageos.org/) can be installed on many **Android devices**, e.g. smartphones and tablets. But it usually needs a computer in the installation process. Is it possible to do it with Ubuntu Linux or is always a Windows system needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can! **All or most of the steps** of the installation LineageOS can be done in Ubuntu Linux, just follow the instructions on the [wiki of LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/device), the instructions depends on the device.

LineageOS can be installed **with Ubuntu (only)** on a lot of devices, e.g.
[Nexus 6P](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/angler/install), [Galaxy S9](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/starlte/install).

But for some devices **access to Windows** is needed for some parts of the installation, e.g. 
- [unlock bootloader of XIAOMI phones](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/mido/install).

In case Windows is needed you can **use Virtualbox** on your Ubuntu Linux computer:

1. Install Virtualbox with a WindowsOS, see [Virtualbox Wiki](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) or this [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986370/how-do-i-install-virtualbox-5-2-gui-on-ubuntu-16-04-3).
2. Be sure to install the **Virtualbox extension pack** is installed, see [Virtual Box Wiki](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing) or this [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack).
3. Activate USB 2.0 or 3.0 in the Virtualbox Settings: Enable USB Controller.
   [image]
4. Open System->Administration->Users, and select your user name. Click "Manage Groups", and scroll down to vboxusers. Click "properties", the make sure your user ID is checked. Re-start VBOX and USB should work. Source: [Softpedia](https://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-VirtualBox-USB-Support-111715.shtml).
5. Then you should be able to connect your Android device with the Windows in the Virtualbox and e.g. do the steps needed to [unlock your XIAOMI smartphone](http://en.miui.com/thread-401381-1-1.html).

Comment: FYI, adding VirtualBox to a certain user group (I forget which exactly lol) is required in order for it to be able to access USB devices.

Comment: My Galaxy S8 required the use of Odin software which was only on Windows. But I managed to run it easily on my existing Windows 10 VM in Ubuntu, with USB passthrough as suggested.