# Unsupported architecture 'i386' when running `apt update` on Virtualbox bionic repo

Tags: apt, 18.04, virtualbox

Encountered this today where there were no issues before, console logs follow:

```
Hit:3 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease
```

---

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Is this a problem with the repository, or with my own config? The same operation had no issue as recently as 3 days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manual comparison of previous [16.04 LTS folder structure](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/xenial/)

> [image: xenial]

with current [18.04 LTS folder structure](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/bionic/)

> [image: bionic]

gives interesting result: it seems that Oracle dropped 32 bit for *bionic* repository.

See information on official [Downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads):

> **VirtualBox binaries**
>
> By downloading, you agree to the terms and conditions of the respective license.
>
> If you're looking for the latest VirtualBox 5.2 packages, see VirtualBox 5.2 builds. >Please also use version 5.2 if you still need support for **32-bit hosts**, as this has been discontinued in 6.0. Version 5.2 will remain supported until July 2020.

So you should change repository line in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` to

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, it works and I can now update the repository without errors. By the way, the method to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` can be referenced from https://askubuntu.com/a/1029865/909537. In summary, run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the path. And marked question as duplicate.

Comment: @weelillad *"I can now update the repository without errors."* It was already updating without errors; the message you got was prefixed with `N`, indicating that it was a **n**otice. **E**rrors are prefixed with `E`.