# manually install VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

Tags: virtualbox

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and have installed `VirtualBox-5.1.38_Ubuntu r122592`. Previously I installed `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` by this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Now I downloaded `VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.18.iso` from `VirtualBox Repository` and copied that in `/usr/share/virtualbox`. I thought that installs newer downloaded archive, but it seems it is not correct, because when I run `$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` get this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
[...]
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso is already the newest version (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1).
```

How I can install that manually?

Comment: I think you do it from the vbox app... there should be an icon in the lower right that lets you install it... or you might need to mount the iso you downloaded in vbox... sorry it's been a while and I am going off of memory of how I did it

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I do not see any thing related to that. Can you post a figure during an answer?

Comment: Been looking everywhere on my Pop_OS install of where the virtualbox guest additions was. Thank you for spelling it out in the description of the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guest additions must meet the Virtual Box release. You can not install newer guest additions in an older Virtual Box release.

Whenever we had installed Virtual Box form the repositories we will also install matching guest additions in the guest from the repos.

In all other instances if we had installed Virtual Box manually from DEB or form the [Oracle repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack) the guest additions ISO will also have been installed.

To access the ISO you will have to mount it in the guest, then run the installer there as root.

See [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) for detailed instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance in about we have to use same versions; but I had problem in sharing clipboard before installing new version, when versions was same. Then I decide to use newer version.

Comment: I reinstalled `virtualbox-guest-additions-5.1.38` again but I have problem in sharing clipboard. I asked another question to describe situations: "https://askubuntu.com/q/1077130/485213". Please see it.