# Problem in sharing clipboard with VirtualBox guest machine

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and have installed `VirtualBox-5.1.38_Ubuntu r122592` and also `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` by this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Previously I created some virtual machines and shared clipboard between Host and Guests (bidirectional). Yesterday I created another guest and did these:

- mounting `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` into the guest
- running `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` in mounted iso (in guest):

  ```
  Verifying archive integrity ... All good.
  Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.1.38 Guest Additions for Linux...........
  VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
  Removing installed version 5.1.38 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
  Copying additional installer modules ...
  Installing additional modules ...
  vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
  ```
- `Devices -> Share Clipboard -> Bidirectional`
- rebooting guest

But "clipboard sharing" is not enabled, however I can do copy/paste between older created guests and host. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is the entry greyed out, or is it just not working as expected? What is your guest OS?

Comment: `Bidirectional` and other options in menu are not grayed (those seems to be in normal state) ;but I cannot do copy/paste between host and guest.

Comment: What is the content of clipboard? It may only work on text or filenames. What guest OS do you run?

Comment: @Takkat That is a text

Comment: Make sure `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` has been installed correctly, I have experiences when I didn't pay attention to `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` output and thought it was installed while it wasn't and was complaining about some packages and kernel headers if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Takkat I added output of running `sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to my question in second bullet. Please see it. Also guest is `Lubuntu 18.04`.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031897/ubuntu-lxde-18-04-and-16-04-virtualbox-bidirectional-clipboard-sharing-not-worki

Comment: @Takkat Thank you for your efforts. I did what was offered for `Lubuntu 18.04` and it works. Can you add an answer then I can accept that and it may be useful for others.

Comment: @hasanghaforian if the answer I linked above helped you we will link this Q & A to the other post so that people will be directed to  it (we call that close as dupe, but in fact it is a brilliant system for internal cross-linking).