# Any alternatives to Virtualbox for virtualization

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What virtualization software can I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use)

Well as the title reads, are there any other virtualization softwares in the mould of virtualbox be it proprietory or open source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KVM is Ubuntu's "official" virtualization platform.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
```

Will get that installed for you. Or read the instructions in Synaptic to see if you machine qualifies (most ordinary PC's will).

Comment: "official"? where it says that?

Comment: From the Ubuntu newsletter. Perhaps "supported" would have been a better word than "official".

**Ubuntu Server Team Focuses on KVM**

With the upcoming LTS release, KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine), will be the virtualization tool of choice for the Server Team. KVM works on x86 hardware containing virtualization extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V), using modified QEMU. Ubuntu 8.04 will also include tools to help manage the KVM. To learn more about KVM, see the interview below with Soren Hansen, virtualization specialist for the Ubuntu Server Team.

Comment: From 2008? Vbox looks more official than KVM

Comment: I would not look for Ubuntu to be making an Oracle product the "official" anything. VBox is a great product, I use it myself. But if you have IP concerns, I would stay away from it. Plus, he ask for something not Vbox, which in Natty, KVM is still a "supported" packages, Vbox is not.