# Installation of Windows 7 from within Ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning, dual-boot, windows-7

My Laptop is installed with Ubuntu 12. Now I want to install Windows 7 along with. Is it possible to keep Ubuntu and Windows in one partition? As in my Laptop computer there in only one partition of 500GB.

Please advise...

Thank you...

Comment: No ,Not at all possible to keep Ubuntu and Windows in **SAME PARTITION**.

Comment: it is not possible. one reason is windows 7 needs NTFS file system and Ubuntu(and all linux variants) needs it to be ext (ext4, ext3,etc.). you can not make a partition of two type of file system .

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't install Windows and Ubuntu in the same partition.

But, I guess, You are referring to the disk by mentioning partition. Yes, You can install Windows and Ubuntu in the same disk by creating separate partition for each OS. In simple word, A partition is a logical division of the whole Disk, so that, You can feel, you have more disk.

Look at these question for getting help in installing Windows after installing Ubuntu:

- [How can I install Windows 7 after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/61218)

Answer (score 0):

You can have both, Windows and Ubuntu on a single partition by installing [Ubuntu insidde Windows using Wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125015/can-i-install-12-04-inside-windows). This means that you will have to repartition your drive to install Windows on this partition first and then install Ubuntu with Wubi on this partition. There is **no way** to install Windows within Ubuntu other than running Windows in a [virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use).

In case you choose to not install Windows in a virtual machine I would recommend you backup your Ubuntu, repartition your drive for a separate Ubuntu, and a Windows partition, and do a fresh install of both operating systems as dual boot.