# Does Scientific Workplace work with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

Before passing to Linux Ubuntu 12.04 I used to have a partition for windows in which I used to work with Scientific Workplace (SW from now on); now I do not have a partition no more and I am a "Ubuntu-one-way-user".

Is there a way to make SW run also on Ubuntu 12.04?

If yes, tell me there is a method which is different from wine, because in my case wine is not working.

Tanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Lyx](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Welcome)

There is an alternative to Scientific Workplace running natively in Ubuntu available free for download from the Software Center. This is definitely worth a look as it does not involve any tweaks that you would need to run Windows software.

[image: Install via the software center]

---

### [Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox/41487#41487)

Virtual Box or any other [virtualization software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use) will enable you to run most Windows software in a virtual machine. This can also be integrated in your desktop but it involves several further steps to perform, and it may not run as smooth as it does on a real machine.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to have all the functions I need to use.