# virtual box or other virtual machine installation and running

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox, virtualization

what is the exact procedure to get VirtualBox running? Or are there reliable alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

[Virtualbox OSE](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox) [image: Install virtualbox] is available fom the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

More recent versions, and also the free but closed source extensions for USB 2.0 support are available from Oracle repositories:

- [How do I install the VirtualBox version from Oracle to install an Extension Pack?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack)

Alternatives are listed in this question & answer:

- [What virtualization software can I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use)