# An application similar to Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, software-recommendation

I would like to know some recommended applications that are similar to VirtualBox. I'm using Ubuntu LTS. The reason I don't want to use VirtualBox is because the installation method requires me to add a repository, and I don't want to use unstable repositories to my system. Like last month when I added the Spotify repository and it made APT very slow, so I decided to remove it to make it fast.

Comment: You do not need to "add a repository" nor "use unstable repository." You just need to enable multiverse and `apt install virtualbox-qt`. If you want similar applications then Googling "Linux virtualization software" returns plenty

Comment: thankf for that sir

Comment: Why would anyone think that this question is asking how to install VBox? It is asking for alternatives to VBox. I vote to reopen and have upvoted.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron This question is about installation because it is an XY problem. This user just wants something that works, not necessarily an alternative. Most of the question body is about assumption unrelated to VirtualBox itself, so the question would need be be edited and improved in order to focus on the alternative part. Furthermore, virtualization has been around for so long that I find it unlikely that there are no duplicates also asking for software recommendations.

Comment: Duplicate of, and should be merged into https://askubuntu.com/questions/41407/what-virtualization-software-can-i-use . See chat.

Answer (score 4):

### Qemu and KVM are both similar to Virtualbox

> QEMU (for Quick Emulator) is a free and open-source emulator. It
> emulates a computer's processor through dynamic binary translation and
> provides a set of different hardware and device models for the
> machine, enabling it to run a variety of guest operating systems. It
> can interoperate with Kernel-based Virtual Machine (KVM) to run
> virtual machines at near-native speed

See https://www.qemu.org/

> KVM (for Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a full virtualization
> solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization
> extensions.

See https://linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page

Comment: Definitely recommend QEMU/KVM, as this is a native virtualization mechanism built into Linux kernel, and not a third-party application like Virtualbox. I wonder why people want to use Virtualbox on Linux at all, if they have a native virtualization solution available at hand...